# Trouble understanding Verilog decoder logical left shift

Tags: verilog, decoder

This code is from asic-world:

```
module decoder_using_assign (
 binary_in   , //  4 bit binary input
 decoder_out , //  16-bit out 
 enable        //  Enable for the decoder
);
  input [3:0] binary_in  ;
  input  enable ; 
  output [15:0] decoder_out ; 

  wire [15:0] decoder_out ; 

  assign decoder_out = (enable) ? (1 << binary_in) : 16'b0 ;

endmodule
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around (1 < < binary_in). binary_in is 4 bits wide, how is the logical left shift producing an output 16 bits wide when enable is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

binary_in is 4 bits, so can hold a decimal value anywhere in the range 0-15.

If you left shift 1 by between 0 and 15, you get a number with at most 16 bits.

16'b0000000000000001 << 0  = 16'b0000000000000001

16'b0000000000000001 << 1  = 16'b0000000000000010

16'b0000000000000001 << 2  = 16'b0000000000000100

...

16'b0000000000000001 << 15 = 16'b1000000000000000